# Bitwise type of function doesn't work. Why?

Tags: typescript

Why the intellisense is required me a parameter in the execution of the function "getCharacters" if its type is a Bitwise ("|").

```
type TGetCharacters = () => Promise<TArrayResponse | null>;
type TGetCharacter = (id: number) => Promise<TCharacter | null>;

type TFnGetData = TGetCharacters | TGetCharacter;

export const getCharacters: TFnGetData = async (id?: number) => {
  const baseURL = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/" + (id || "");
  const res = await fetch(baseURL);

  const isFailure = !(res.ok && res.status === 200);

  if (isFailure) return null;

  return await res.json();
};

const characters = await getCharacters();
```

If it receives an "id" then the return type is TCharacter, else it is TArrayResponse.

```
Excepted 1 arguments, but got 0. ts(2554)
index.ts(32, 23): An argument for 'id' was not provided.
```

```
(alias) getCharacters(id: number): Promise<TCharacter | null> | Promise<TArrayResponse | null>
import getCharacters
```

Please help me understand the warning and if possible how to improve the code.

I would like the type is outside of the function, not inside the function. Is that possible?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] we can test ourselves, where you either define or remove `TArrayResponse` and `TCharacter`.

Comment: `const isFailure = res.ok && res.status === 200;` Are you sure about this? I think you missed the negate or the variable name should be `isNotAFailure`

Comment: You're right, thank you very much for the correction <3; However, it does not have to do with the core of the problem because when correcting it, the intellisense continues to show the same warning.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the `|` here is a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) and has nothing to do with bitwise operations.

TypeScript doesn't care much about the actual value of `getCharacters`, which here is of type `(id?: number) => something`. It only cares that the value you provided is compatible with the type you declared, which here is `TFnGetData`. Since it's compatible, TypeScript gives you no issues here, but from now on, TypeScript will only assume that `getCharacters` is of type `TFnGetData`.

So the question becomes, why does a `TFnGetData` call require a parameter?

When you union two callable types, TypeScript will attempt to merge the parameters and return types to create a new callable type. If you inspect `TFnGetData`, you should see that it is equivalent to

```js
type TFnGetData = (id: number) => Promise<TArrayResponse | null> | Promise<TCharacter | null>
```

This type kept the first argument of `TGetCharacter` (which is a non-optional `number`) because `TGetCharacters` didn't have a first argument, and the return type is a union of the return types of `TGetCharacters` and `TGetCharacter`.